# Is there a name for "inverted ball"?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a name for "inverted ball", that is a body filling the whole Euclidean space with a ball cut off?

Comment: What do you mean by a "ball cut-off" ? Your question should be made clearer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the use of "exterior of a ball" or naturally "complement of the ball". I have never found one-word name for it.

Comment: ... More a comment than a true answer...

Comment: I have just read the formal difference between answer and comment on Meta. Now I am agree with you but unfortunately it looks like I cannot delete an accepted answer.

Comment: No problem ! Continue to answer, this is the most important in order that this site remains a living site...